# Using Scanner to read file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am using Scanner to read the text file which contains *, spaces and alphabets. Two or more spaces can occur one after the other. Eg:

```
****  AAAAA* *    ****
    *******    AAAAAA*** *
```

I have written the following code:

```
lineTokenizer = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
int i=0;
if (lineTokenizer.hasNext()) {
    //lineTokenizer.useDelimiter("\\s");
    System.out.println(lineTokenizer.next());
    //maze[0][i]=lineTokenizer.next();
    i++;
}
```

The lineTokenizer doesn't read beyond the * from the input file not are the characters getting stored in the maze array. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I cannot guess it from your description.

Comment: @RomainSertelon I am trying to read the file and put it into a 2D array. The lines in the file may have 2/more whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `FileInputStreams` to read the file with a `BufferedReader`.

I personnally use the `Scanner` only for console input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using loops instead of just if.

Try changing the 3rd line to:

```
while (lineTokenizer.hasNext())
```

Comment: But isn't the lineTokenizer.hasNext() supposed to read the characters in ONE line? Maybe I should put the s.nextLine() in a while. But how can I read TWO spaces one after the other??

Comment: lineTokenizer.hasNext() checks if there are still any tokens left. It does not advance to the next token. Using the first line of input, what would you want to achieve? Do you want to get "****", "AAAAA*", etc.?

Comment: I want to get the spaces too. In the code I've written, the reading stops after the spaces are encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an *if* condition, the pointer is not moving ahead. You should use a loop to continuously read data from scanner. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, tried adding the while but it doesn't move beyond  once it encounters the whitespace.

Comment: Well it depends on condition you use inside while.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code is changed many times while you tried different stuff.
I don't know how you handle the initialization of **maze** but to avoid any ArrayIndexOutOfBounds I would use a List in a List instead.
I made some guesses about what you wanted and propose this:

```
List<List<String>> maze = new ArrayList<>();        
Scanner s = new Scanner("****  AAAAA* *    ****\n    *******    AAAAAA*** *");
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    List<String> line = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner lineTokenizer = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
    lineTokenizer.useDelimiter("\\s+");
    while (lineTokenizer.hasNext()) {
        String data = lineTokenizer.next();
        System.out.println(data);
        line.add(data);
    }
    lineTokenizer.close();
    maze.add(line);
}
s.close();
```

I did not fully understand your goals. Does this do about what you want?
The code above will give you the following list: `[[****, AAAAA*, *, ****], [*******, AAAAAA***, *]]`

Comment: Thanks. But I want to read the consecutive whitespaces from the file (char by char)and store them in individual 2D array cells.